# What is $A\setminus B$ Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces

In this discussion S & C both represent sets.

I have been reading symbols like "\" in linear algebra like something, a subset $C\subset S$ is *closed* if $S\setminus C$ is open. Now, I know that in mathematics "/" represents quotient space like quotient space of S in C is written as $C/S$ but I am unable to figure out what does $S/C$ means. Please, help me out. Is it another way to represent $S-C$?

Can anyone please tell me what does this statement actually mean? "A subset $C\subset S$ is *closed* if $S\setminus C$ is open."

Comment: Yes, it is the same as $S-C$.

Comment: As been said $S - C = S \setminus C$. The former is an older notation, and I would not be surprised if the latter will eventually be (or is) the prevalent notation.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as $S-C$.  In other words, all points in $S$ that do not belong to $C$.